# Issue on login with stackexchange login

Tags: bug, login, stack-exchange-openid

I've created a stackexchange account because of the drop of openID.
Thus, I wanted to add this account to my logins in SO.

Here are the steps I followed:

- Checkout stackoverflow
- click on the header to view my profile
- click "my logins"
- "add more logins"
- "log in with StackExchange"
- Filed the email / password fields
- clicked sign in button

And there I got the "page not found" error.

It finally worked the day after I contacted the support for that issue, but they asked me to report the issue here.

Today I wanted to login, and I experienced the same kind of issue. I did a [screencast](http://www.fser.lautre.net/stackoverflow-login-failure.ogv)  of the issue.

I hope this helps.